# Readfile problem - file downloaded include the file path and i don't know how to remove

Tags: php, http, download

The following code is properly working, but there is a little problem: the first line of the file downloaded has the path of the file. Don't know why, here's the code: [image: file output]

```
function aprifile()
    {
        $url = './file/'.$_POST['seconda'];
        echo $url;
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$_POST[seconda]");
        readfile($url);
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: Remove the `echo $url;`.

Comment: but why it was printing on the file? I hadn't already open it

Comment: Read ADyson's answer...

Answer (score 1):

`echo $url;` is the culprit.

It's important to realise that anything you output from PHP becomes part of the response going back to the browser. You've told the browser that the response is to be treated as a downloadable file rather than a HTML page.

`readFile` does the same thing as `echo`, except from a file instead of a variable - it reads the content of the file and puts it in PHP's output buffer.

If you want to add something like that for debugging, you need to make it log to a file on the server, not echo it as part of the output.